# Conditional render with the hook: UseState

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, state

I'm junior developer whose main task is to develop a event that change into another event when you click a button. Kinda this:

[image]

In step, this is how I did and it didnt work:

[image]

I wanna know how can I conditional render both component in order change one after another how the first gif implies?

This is my code:

```
function Event(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1> Nueva carga de archivo...</h1>
      <p class="Message"> Nueva base de datos Jun22xls</p>
      <progress value="10" max="100">
        75%
      </progress>
    </>
  );
}

function eventUpdated(props) {
  return <h1>Archivo Cargado exitosamente</h1>;
}

function Progressbar(props) {
  const [state, setNewState] = useState(true);
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;

  const HandleLogin = useCallback(() => {
    setNewState((prevstate) => ({ state: !state.prevstate }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div class="Container">
      {state ? <Event /> : <eventUpdated />}
      <AiOutlineCloseCircle className="close-icon" onClick={HandleLogin} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If anyone could provide me so useful help or advice; I'd really be grateful.

Thanks and have a nice nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use the `setNewState` is not correct, you should do :

```
const HandleLogin = useCallback(() => {
    setNewState((prevstate) => !prevstate);
  }, []);
```

`state.prevstate` would assume that your `state` is an object with the attribute `prevstate` but your `state` is boolean.

`prevstate` is already your previous state so if `prevstate` is `true` returning `!prevstate` would update the state to false.

Check the doc here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Thanks buddy! Nevertheless, the component render, but how can I do for the close Icon changes too? I wanna hide it when I click it.

Comment: The `<AiOutlineCloseCircle className="close-icon" onClick={HandleLogin} />`?

Comment: You can replace it by `{state && <AiOutlineCloseCircle className="close-icon" onClick={HandleLogin} />}`